# Flutter change grandparent container after a grandchild element is clicked

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies

here is my code, and the goal is when I tap on one of the `WidgetBouquet` i want to change the whole child of `BouquetScreenState`  from  `child: GetBouquets()` to another widget named GetProducts().

```
 // ******************* BouquetScreenState main Widget
class BouquetScreenState extends StatefulWidget {
  _BouquetScreenState createState() => _BouquetScreenState();
}
class _BouquetScreenState extends State<BouquetScreenState> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Container(
      // onTap WidgetBouquet the child here becomes GetProducts instead of GetBouquets
      child: GetBouquets(),
    );
  }

// ******************* GetBouquets child Widget
class GetBouquets extends StatefulWidget {
  GetBouquetsState createState() => GetBouquetsState();
}

class GetBouquetsState extends State<GetBouquets> {
  final ScrollController _scroll = ScrollController();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder<List<Bouquet>>(
      future: fetchBouquets(),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (!snapshot.hasData)
          return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
        else {
          return Container(
            child: Scrollbar(
              isAlwaysShown: true,
              controller: _scroll,
              child: GridView.builder(
                controller: _scroll,
                gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                  crossAxisCount: 2,
                  childAspectRatio: 0.8,
                  crossAxisSpacing: 1,
                  mainAxisSpacing: 25,
                ),
                itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
                itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                  return WidgetBouquet(snapshot.data[index]);
                }
              ),
            ),
          );
        }
      },
    );
  }
}

 // ******************* WidgetBouquet Grandchild Widget
class WidgetBouquet extends StatefulWidget {
  final Bouquet data;
  WidgetBouquet(this.data);
  _BouquetState createState() => _BouquetState();
}

class _BouquetState extends State<WidgetBouquet> {
  String nom;
  String error;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    nom = widget.data.nom;
    return Container(
      child: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
        children: [
          Expanded(
            child: GestureDetector(
               // ** if this container is clicked change the  child: GetBouquets() to  
                   child: GetProducts(),
              child: Container(
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15.0),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Solution 1

```dart
class _BouquetScreenState extends State<BouquetScreenState> {
  // add this
  bool showBouquets = true; // if true show Bouquets, else show Products
  void goToProducts() {
    setState(() {
      showBouquets = false;
    });
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    if (showBouquets) return GetBouquets(goToProducts);
    else return GetProducts();
  }
}

class GetBouquets extends StatefulWidget {
  // add these 2 lines (need to do the same for WidgetBouquet)
  final void Function() goToProjects;
  GetBouquets(this.goToProjects);
  // rest is unchanged
  GetBouquetsState createState() => GetBouquetsState();
}
```

And pass `goToProducts` to GetBouquets and WidgetBouquet.

### Solution 2

Use [provider](https://pub.dev/packages/provider) to not have to pass down the method through all the widgets

Comment: amazing i'll try and update you if it works

Comment: having issues passing the method how to do that ?

Comment: I've added the constructor to the GetBouquets class in my answer

Answer (score 1):

Have a public `bool isClicked = false;`
and then use it as a children as follows:

```
     Expanded(
                child: GestureDetector(
                   onTap: () {
                setState((){
                 isClicked =!isClicked
                });},
                      child: isClicked ? GetProducts() : GetBouquets() ,
                  child: Container(
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15.0),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
```

What this does it that if the bool is true, it will take the first child. If it's false, it will render the second one.

Comment: You can also wrap it in AnimatedSwitcher or something to make it look better.

Comment: isClicked is defined in main widget BouquetScreenState , but cannot access it in the child WidgetBouquet , widgets are on separate files

Comment: how i pass it ?

Comment: can you define it outside the state? Like this: https://prnt.sc/13pwf8c